# NVIDIAドライバが正しくインストールされていない？

Tags: linux, gpu

Ubuntu16.04 LTS にて、tensorflowを使うためにグラフィクスドライバ周辺を色々入れていて、以前は問題なく動いていたのですが、OSのアップデート（18.04LTS）をきっかけに動作が不安定になりました。
そのため、OSをダウングレードし、16.04LTSに戻したのですが、どうもドライバのインストールがうまく出来ていないようです。

インストールを試したNVIDIAドライバは 410, 396, 384（※ "＄apt-cache search" にて検索）
CUDA tool-kit はver9，ver10

基本的にこうしたらできました、という記事をいくらか回ったりなどしたため、基本手順は一般的なものと思います。

```
$ nvidia-smi
```

が実行できていないため、ドライバのインストールができていないと判断をしています。
何か手違いなどがあるのでしょうか？
どなたかご教授願えますでしょうか。

**環境：**
OS/Ubuntu16.04 LTS
GPU/GeForce GTX1080
CPU/Intel Core i7-6800K

Comment: 念のためいくつか確認させてください。「16.04の状態でドライバを入れてOSのアップグレードをしたけど不安定なので元に戻した」後、ドライバの再インストールは試されましたか？ / OSのダウングレードとはどのような手順で行いましたか？私はLinuxのダウングレードは経験がありませんが、アップグレード時などは互換性がなくなるパッケージは削除や置き換えされる場合があった気がします。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。ダウングレード、は言い方が良くなかったようです。正しくはOSの再インストールです。それから必要なドライバなどを0からインストールしたことになります。その状態で最初は動いていたのですが、どこかでドライバの更新をしたときに動作不良を起こし、それ以降にドライバを削除、再インストールなどをしても動かない、といった状況です。